# print sum after every two observation

Tags: sas

We have dataset a like this

```
data a;
   length id 8 actlevel $6 fee 8;
   infile datalines;
   input id actlevel fee;
   datalines;
1 High 85.20
2 High 124.80
3 Low 149.75
4 Medium 149.75
5 Low 124.80
;
run;
```

We have to print output like this

```
id  actlevel fee

1    High   85.20
2    High   124.80
Act Level  210.0

3 Low 149.75
4 Low 124.80
Act Level 274.55

5 Medium 149.75    
Act level 634.30
```

I am using the code:

```
proc sort data=a;
   by actlevel;
run;

data total;
   set a;
   by actlevel;

   if first.actlevel then
      sum1=0;
   sum1+fee;

   if last.actlevel then
      output;
   drop fee;
run;

proc print data=total;
   sum sum1;
run;
```

First print sum of first two observation(by actlevel) & then print sum of another two(by actlevel) observation in last print sum of all 5 observation.

Comment: Please clarify your question, it's unclear.  And in the future format your question appropriately. I did this time, but if you don't take the time to do so, it's likely people won't take the time to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need any preprocesing in data step to have output similar to one you specified. `proc print` procedure have something like `sumby` to do this job.

```
proc sort data=a;
   by actlevel;
run;

proc print data=a;
   by actlevel;
   sumby actlevel;
   sum fee;
run;
```